# Нужна ли эта запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно будет "Она гуглит сколько лепестков у роз"? Или "Она гуглит, сколько лепестков у роз"?

Comment: Аналогично фразе: «Я спросил у тополя, где моя любимая. [Эльдар Рязанов, Эмиль Брагинский. Ирония судьбы, или С легким паром (1969)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Гуглить](https://comp_slang.academic.ru/65/%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) — пользоваться поисковой системой Google, искать информацию в интернете с помощью Google.
[Сколько](http://endic.ru/kuzhecov/Skolko-46595.html) — III. *союзн. сл.* Употребляется в придаточных дополнительных, придаточных определительных предложениях и в предложениях степени и меры. *Не могу сказать, до скольких градусов достигала стужа. Выдохнул весь воздух, сколько его было в лёгких. Поживи, сколько я пожил.*

С запятой, без вопросительного знака:
***Она гуглит, сколько лепестков*** [есть] ***у роз.***

― Я знаю, сколько такой журнал стоит, аккурат вся моя пенсия уйдет, не куплю его. [Дарья Донцова. Уха из золотой рыбки (2004)]

С двоеточием и вопросительным знаком (можно поставить *а именно*):
***Она гуглит*** [= ищет информацию]***: сколько лепестков у роз?***